# Use autoplay to play a radio station using HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, internet-radio

I'm trying to launch automatically a webradio on my html's file. Currently using autoplay fails, I assume the radio miss the time to load some data hence the autoplay just block.
I have created a setTimeout function to handle that. Now the function refuses to launch on Firefox and Opera. The error log of Firefox is far most informative, here reproduced:

> NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or
>   the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied
>   permission

here my html's snippet:

```html
<body>
  <audio controls src="http://5.63.151.52:7136/stream?icy=http" autoplay id="myAudio">
                Your browser does not support the
                <code>audio</code> element.
        </audio>

  <button onclick={goPlay()}>
            Play
        </button>

  <script>
    // function goPlay(){
    //     console.log("in goplay")
    setTimeout(() => {
        var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        // function playAudio() {
        x.play();
      },
      1000
    )
    // }
  </script>
</body>
```

How handle this situation?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Autoplay is getting [phased](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay) out slowly from most major browsers.

Comment: Is this React or Handlebars or ...? `<button onclick={goPlay()}>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firefox error is telling you exactly what's happening. The autoplay isn't working because the user (or more specifically, the browser - see [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/02/firefox-66-to-block-automatically-playing-audible-video-and-audio/)) is blocking it.

> Any playback that happens before the user has interacted with a page
>   via a mouse click, printable key press, or touch event, is deemed to
>   be autoplay and will be blocked if it is potentially audible.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I tried to execute `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].play()` in the browser console, above the error message you mentioned, there was a warning `Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted.`. I was able to execute the code by muting the video first or selecting "Allow Audio and Video" for the website permissions in Firefox.

Comment: Yes currently some browsers restrict the autoplay's function to preserve the serenity of their user, it can lead to error effectively.